# Why is it a pointer?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objective c difference between id and void *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void)
>   [why most of the objects we create in iphone are pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044292/why-most-of-the-objects-we-create-in-iphone-are-pointers)

According to Stanford university course, 2010/2011

Lecture 3

The guy made something strange there (at least for me), which is that

```
NSString *digit = sender.titlelabel.text;
```

Why is digit a pointer?

Comment: Among others: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+why+use+pointers&submit=search

Comment: Actually, this is the answer I meant to point to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething/2214980#2214980  It attempts to describe exactly what the difference is between, say, `NSString*` and `NSString` (without the *).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of your `digit` is `id`, which is just basically just a C pointer to a certain struct. *All* references to objects in Objective-C have this primitive type, regardless of the Class of the object. So the answer to your question is, unfortunately, *because that's the way Objective-C works*.

So whether you're declaring an `NSString*`, or an `UITableViewController*`, or `MyClass*`, your variable has type `id`. This is the primary means by which the language implements polymorphism. So, for example, the following declarations are equivalent:

```
NSString *digit;
id digit;
```

And it's true of method prototypes as well. These are equivalent:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(id)tableView:(id)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(id)indexPath;
```

A variable of type `id` is not an object itself, it is a pointer to an object. It is the handle with which you manipulate an object. Objective-C does all of the class compatibility work at runtime.

Hope this helps. Any questions?

Updates

That's right: `int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, `void`, and the pointer combinations, are all C primitive types. You can and will still use these quite a bit, and they are just what they are in a C program. But Objective-C adds the `id` type as a way to bridge the gap between the primitive typing of C and the very high-level typing of objects by the Objective-C system. `id` itself is typedef'd as a pointer to a simple struct in [`objc.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.2/runtime/objc.h). At the level of the compiler and the language itself, there really isn't too much meaning to the type. For example, you'll almost never declare an array of `id`s, certainly never perform any arithmetic with them.

In fact, it's not too far a stretch to say that Objective-C is just plain vanilla C with some added syntax (particularly, the square-bracket notation for method invocation), a few extra primitive types (`id`, `IMP`, `SEL`), and a big runtime library. It's this runtime library that handles all things Object-Oriented.

Anyway, to answer your question, when you're actually programming, you will most often (99% of the time) just use class names to declare your variables - `NSString *`, `NSData *`, `UITableViewController *`, and so on. And the compiler will know what you're talking about, and issue a *warning* if you write code that clearly tries to put an `NSString*` where an `NSData*` is expected. But the actual meaning of those types really exists only at runtime.

I've digressed a little, but I'm not sure where your understanding is failing you, so I thought I'd just explain things a bit. You might want to read Apple's [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163) to get a feel for the language.

Comment: But some stuff are declared like this

int X
float Y

I know these are C stuff (I'm actually C/C++ intermediate~professional algorithm programmer), so ONLY Objective-C objects use this way or what?

Comment: Checking this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething/2214980#2214980

I figured out the same point. But since it uses pointers, all objects would be accessible by all other objects. It would just work with the memory. It turns a blind eye to whatever it belongs to, and nothing can prevent it. Right?

Comment: That's right, kind of. It's the *compiler* that turns a blind eye to OO. Objective-C has two levels of type - primitive and OO. Primitive types - int, float, et al from C - along with Obj-C's additions of id, SEL, IMP - are primitive and enforced by the compiler. The OO typing system - *all of it* - NSString, etc, with NSObject at root  - are OO types, but OO semantics (encapsulation, polymorphism, etc) are enforced by the runtime system. The compiler *will* pick up on obvious OO type conflicts, but these will only result in a warning, not an error. Read the docs, I'm out of characters!

Answer (score 1):

[`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) is an Objective-C class and all object references in Objective-C are pointers. I would suggest reading through some of the documentation such as [Learning Objective-C A Primer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html):

> Notice the * in the first declaration. In Objective-C, object
>   references are pointers. If this doesn’t make complete sense to you,
>   don’t worry—you don’t have to be an expert with pointers to be able to
>   start programming with Objective-C. You just have to remember to put
>   the * in front of the variable names for strongly-typed object
>   declarations. The id type implies a pointer.

Comment: Reading reading reading... I like reading, but most of stuff are just pages and pages, and you can't find the single line containing your answer for ages

Anyway, that solves me. I concluded that NSString's are ALWAYS pointers.

By the way, what other objects are always pointers?

EDIT: After seeing Josh's answer, I found it. Thanks :)

Comment: I added a quote from the link I posted. The only thing required to be a pointer in Objective-C are references to the classes (an instance of the class). So primitive types like ints, doubles, or even structs can be declared without a pointer. Also if you were to mix C++ and Objective-C the C++ classes can still be declared on the stack (no pointer).

Comment: No, NSString's are not always pointers. One *refers* to NSStrings usually by pointers.

Comment: Ah...

Doesn't he want to "create" an NSString called digit to put text there? Why does he make it as a pointer?

Comment: @joe yeah, there was a race condition, and I forgot to address my comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a digit, it's the "text" from the label, which is (I'm guessing) a string of integers and such to express the time.

So, all NSString types are declared as pointers in Obj-c.

```
 sender.titlelabel.text;
```

Returns a NSString *

Remember, it's the same as:

```
NSString *str  = [sender.titlelabel getText];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `text` is too. Or more preceisly, because the `getText` message returns a pointer.

Comment: Are you sure about that point? I guess that's the most clear and convincing answer for it, that getText returns a pointer :/

Comment: While that is true about matching the return type, it is more in-depth than that. When you declare a reference to an Objective-C class it will always be declared as a pointer.

Comment: @Joe While you are right, there is even more in-depth than that. One *could* construct an ObjC object (as a stack object) and reference it like, e.g., a struct. However, this is not how it is usually done. Rather, one lets it's class construct that (anonymous) object; and the class returns a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an intersting about why it has to be a pointer:

[NSString and Pointers](http://cocoadev.com/forums/discussion/1323/nsstring-and-pointers/p1)

 I Hope it will help you to understand it in a Objective-C way.